# Third party library (react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient) gets empty object on require('chalk')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am running a react app using the Webpack dev server. In the config, I have 'react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient' as a party of the entry array.

This prompts the following error:
[image: error]

I can't figure out what could be causing this.

I have verified that chalk is present in the node_modules folder, and it's the correct version.

I am using yarn workspaces, and the node_modules is in a root directory. Maybe this could be causing the error. However, I have no idea how to fix it.

The Webpack config I am using can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Fralleee/ba768298932722c6494a1759ab4def31

Comment: Since you're using yarn workspaces, make sure there the `require` isn't picking up an different version of `chalk` from a node_modules other than your root workspace node_modules.

Comment: Ok so I think I figured out the problem, no idea how to solve it though.

In a project where the error overlay is working the react-dev-utils folder has it's own "node_modules"-folder with chalk in it.
https://i.imgur.com/NExfDPA.png


However in my current project react-dev-utils/node_modules does not include chalk since the same version exists in my root node_modules folder.

It just does not seem to resolve the dependency correctly :(

Comment: Have you overwritten the webpack `resolve` field in your webpack config file?

if `chalk` is imported inside `react-dev-utils` or from any file underneath that directory then it'll pick up the `chalk` from the closest node_modules.

Since your project is higher up than `react-dev-utils` I'd expect any `import` to resolve to the root node_modules dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Resolved" the issue by downgrading "react-dev-utils" to version "7.0.1". Don't know why e.t.c.

Found this thread with *some* information:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6214